# How to return error messages in JSON with Bottle HTTPError?

Tags: python, json, bottle

I have a bottle server that returns HTTPErrors as such:

```
return HTTPError(400, "Object already exists with that name")
```

When I receive this response in the browser, I'd like to be able to pick out the error message given. As it is right now I can see the error message in the response's `responseText` field, but it's buried in an HTML string that I'd rather not parse if I don't have to.

Is there any way I can specifically set the error message in Bottle so I can pick it out in JSON in the browser?

Comment: Unrelated, but...Is that an actual error? If so, it shouldn't be a `400` status code. A `409 Conflict` should be returned IMHO,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`HTTPError` uses a predefined HTML template to build the body of the response. Instead of using `HTTPError` you can use `response` with the appropriate status code and body.

```
import json
from bottle import run, route, response

@route('/text')
def get_text():
    response.status = 400
    return 'Object already exists with that name'

@route('/json')
def get_json():
    response.status = 400
    response.content_type = 'application/json'
    return json.dumps({'error': 'Object already exists with that name'})

# Start bottle server.
run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8070, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for a similar way, to handle all error messages as JSON responses. The problem with the above solution is, that they don't do it in a nice and generic way, i.e. to handle any possible popping error, not just a defined 400 etc. Imho the cleanest solution is, to override the default error, and then work with a custom bottle object:

```
class JSONErrorBottle(bottle.Bottle):
    def default_error_handler(self, res):
        bottle.response.content_type = 'application/json'
        return json.dumps(dict(error=res.body, status_code=res.status_code))
```

The passed `res` argument has some more attributes about the thrown error, which may be returned, see the code for the default template for that. Especially `.status`, `.exception` and `.traceback` seem relevant.

Comment: it would be useful if you described how to use a class like this. Simply declaring the class on its own doesn't seem to do anything - how do you tell Bottle to use this as its default error handler?

Answer (score 4):

only just started working with bottle but would recommend something more along the lines of:

```
import json
from bottle import route, response, error, abort

@route('/text')
def get_text():
    abort(400, 'object already exists with that name')

# note you can add in whatever other error numbers
# you want, haven't found a catch-all yet
# may also be @application.error(400)
@error(400) #might be @application.error in some usages i think.
def json_error(error):
    """for some reason bottle don't deal with 
    dicts returned the same way it does in view methods.
    """
    error_data = {
        'error_message': error.body
    }
    response.content_type = 'application/json'
    return json.dumps(error_data)
```

didn't run the above so expect mistakes, but you get the gist.